# JavaFX Rectangle stops ComboBox displaying drop-down

Tags: javafx, combobox, resize

I have a requirement to display a Rectangle with an InnerShadow effect as the background of my JavaFX nodes. Each node needs to be resizable. I am implementing this with an abstract base class with a Region which has the Rectangle with an InnerShadow as one of its children and a Region provided by the concrete implementation of this class as its other child.

The problem occurs when I add one or more ComboBoxes to the child region. Clicking on the ComboBoxes has no effect, i.e. they do not display their drop-down list of items.

I have tried making the Rectangle smaller (i.e. 10x10 pixels) so that it does not overlap the ComboBoxes. This makes no difference.

```
private void createNodeWithBackground() {
    pane = new Region() {
        @Override
        public void resize(double width, double height) {
            super.resize(width, height);

            backing = new Rectangle(width, height);
            InnerShadow shadeEffect = new InnerShadow();
            shadeEffect.setWidth(w/2);
            shadeEffect.setHeight(h/2);
            shadeEffect.setInput(new ColorAdjust(-0.1, 0.2, -0.1, 0.1));
            backing.setEffect(shadeEffect);

            getChildren().clear();
            getChildren().addAll(backing, getBodyNode());
        }
    };
    getChildren().add(pane);
}

/**
 * The concrete class provides a node to be displayed on top of the
 * Rectangle with the InnerShadow.
 * This might be a VBox containing a ComboBox and other nodes.
 */
protected abstract Region getBodyNode();
```

Removing the Rectangle from the scene results in the ComboBoxes displaying drop-down lists as expected.

Comment: Post a [MCVE] if you are not satisfied with your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Using javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox instead of javafx.scene.control.ComboBox resolves this issue, although I have no idea why.